# error installing padrino-cache gem on windows xp, ruby 1.9.2p180 and devkit

Tags: ruby, windows, installation, padrino

```
gem update padrino-cache

Updating installed gems
Updating padrino-cache
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
Invalid argument - C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/padrino-cache-0.9.25/test/tmp/#<class:0x0000010084e5a8>

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the gem and how it's specification (manifest) was generated.

You can see the gem contents doing `gem spec padrino-cache -v 0.9.25 files`

You will see something like this:

```
- test/tmp/#<class:0x108b3b4e8>/cache/%2Ffoo
- test/tmp/#<class:0x108b3b588>/cache/%2Ffoo
- test/tmp/#<class:0x108b3b718>/cache/%2Ffoo
- test/tmp/#<class:0x108b46640>/cache/test
- test/tmp/#<class:0x108b5fdc0>/cache/test
- test/tmp/#<class:0x108b60c98>/cache/bar
- test/tmp/#<class:0x108b60c98>/cache/foo
- test/tmp/#<class:0x108b61b20>/cache/test
```

The files included in the gem contains colons, which is used on Windows to indicate drive letters and are not allowed as part of file name.

I will recommend report this to Padrino Framework bug tracker:

https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/issues

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in hotfix release 0.9.26. Read more here: http://www.padrinorb.com/blog/padrino-0-9-26-hotfix-release